# AngularJS table with data from JSON with CoffeeScript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a table with content from a json file. I'm using AngularJS and CoffeeScript. Both are relatively new to me and I'm making small changes to existing code from a bought [admin app](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/transform-multi-layout-flat-admin-app-WB068HT8D)

Now I have this CoffeeScript:

```
'use strict'
angular.module('app.tables', [])

.controller('tableCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$filter', '$http'
    ($scope, $filter, $http) ->
      # filter

      $http.get('/data/file.json').success (data) ->
        console.log data
        $scope.stores = data

      console.log $scope.stores
```

When running this code, in the console I will first seen a "undefined" log of the 2nd console.log. After that, the 1st console.log is displayed and it contains the object with content of file.json.

But later in the code, `$scope.stores` is used, which is empty. How is this working?

I think my problem is that with `$http.get` my data is loaded asynchronous while the javascript continous and `$scope.stores` is not yet supplied with data. How will I first load the data? Or append the table with the loaded data when success.

Comment: Yes, it's because the data is loaded asynchronously by `$http`

Comment: There is also a init() function in this code. Running this function in the 'http.get().success' inits the table and fills it with the data from the json table. Working for now, not the most beautiful way because I need to initialize an empty '$scope.stores'. But it is working!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to run an init function. Angular supports data binding, so when the data is fetched, it should update the View accordingly. There is no need for a special init function.